# Bear attacks siege engine (Trying to find name of anime)

Tags: the-twelve-kingdoms

I watched a clip many years ago, and I'd now like to try to find the anime it went with. Unfortunately, I lost the clip in a computer transfer, so here's what I remember:

- The clip was downloaded around 2005-2007. So the anime would have been made before then. The art was polished enough that it would have been made in the 80s at the very earliest. Probably 90s or early 2000s.
- The scene had two people standing near the gate of a castle. They were being attacked by an army, and one of the two people charged into battle. I believe he attacked with a polearm for a few moments first, but the most memorable part of the scene was his transformation into a giant animal (a bear, I think). The transformation didn't get any special scene, it just happened quickly as part of the action. After transforming, he began to wreck the battlefield, including flipping a siege engine.
- The animation was more realistic than cartoony (more like Steamboy or Attack on Titan than Azumanga Daioh! or Soul Eater).

I realise this is very little to go off of, but if anyone has any ideas or half-remembered memories, let's see if we can't figure this out, shall we?

Comment: If there is a downvote, I'd appreciate a reason why my question is considered unacceptable for this stack. After checking with the rules here http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/we-need-to-do-something-about-the-new-users-behind-identification-request-questi/2473#2473, I've verified my question meets the bare minimum for id requests. I'm happy for any constructive criticism, but downvotes without comments gives me nothing I can use to improve my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the anime of [The Twelve Kingdoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Kingdoms).

The 'bear' you're thinking of is a *hanyuu* (those able to turn to human and back), Kantai:

[image: Kantai]

The memorable scene of him flipping the siege engine occurs late during the third arc, *A Great Distance in the Wind, the Sky at Dawn* (unfortunately, I can't recall the exact episode, but it's almost certainly 37-39.)

Comment: Thank you very much! It was in [episode 38](https://youtu.be/Ng-MPWZQHdU?t=783), 13:03-14:40.